# Spring Cloud microservice with keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, keycloak, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a spring cloud microservices project which uses Spring Cloud Config Server for managing configurations and Eureka Server for service discovery.

My application was doing great until I wanted to add a new microservice with keycloak. This new microservice is simply a rest API for my Vue frontend application and user managament is expected to be handled by Keycloak.

The new service runs OK and registers itself to Eureka **until** I add keycloak dependencies to the project. Application does not crash or throw any errors, startsup fine and registers itself to Eureka but on the Spring Boot Admin server panel I see that the application is down.

Here is my .properties file for the new service.

```
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=3
eureka.client.eureka-connection-idle-timeout-seconds=3
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true

spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://localhost:6060
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always

server.port=8082

keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.realm=microservices
keycloak.resource=microservices-app
keycloak.public-client=true

keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=user
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/*
keycloak.cors=true
```

Here are my dependencies for the new service.

```xml
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.3.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Spring cloud version is `Hoxton.SR1`

Spring boot version is `2.2.2.RELEASE`

I have tried adding Spring Security and making java configurations using `KeycloakAuthenticationProvider` but didn't help.

Throughout this project, I had many weird bugs caused by Spring Cloud version or Spring Cloud-Spring Boot Admin interaction so changing version or adding one little parameter to the configuration files usually did the trick, I am suspecting this Keycloak issue will be solved the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot Admin uses actuator endpoints, try to make them unprotected:

```
    keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=user
    keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/*
    keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[1].patterns[0]=/actuator
    keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[1].patterns[1]=/actuator/*
```

Comment: Adding these endpoints fixed the problem. I ended up removing these endpoint configurations from properties, permit all endpoints from Spring Security and use `@PreAuthorize` to restrict access to endpoints.

Comment: @gadria Hello, i'm trying to implement the same architecture, and i'm struggling right now due to the lack of resources in using Spring cloud with keycloak. So my situation is that i have this simple ER diagram where a "User" table has a One-To-Many relationship with another table called "Orders". And Keycloak does provide us to use MySQL instead of H2, but i was wondering is it possible to have my diagram used by Keycloak ? and can i do CRUD operations like if i delete a user then delete is cascaded to his orders too ?

Comment: How is cascading crud operations related to keycloak?